# sum up values according to string condition of a list generated by a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sum, export-to-csv

My code searches for particular files and calls upon a separate .py file to output some data. I manually appended a row for the file size of each file. I simply want to append to the end of the iterations the sum of all of the file sizes of the files found. I guess this would involve using boolean indexing, however I could not find any good reference. I want to find all the columns that are labelled 'file sizes' and then sum all of their values.

---

one sample iteration (I randomly put many 'file sizes' near each other, but in the real data, it would be separated by about 15 lines)

```
xd = """Version 3.1.5.0
GetFileName C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads\\higgi022_20150612_007_bsadig_100fm_aft_newIonTrap3.raw
GetCreatorID    thermo
GetVersionNumber    64
file size   1010058
file size   200038
file size   48576986
file size   387905
misc    tester
more    python"""
```

---

at the end of the for loop I want to sum all the file sizes (this is very wrong but this is my best attempt):

```
zd = xd.split()
for aline in zd:
    if 'file size' in aline:
        sum = 0
        for eachitem in aline[1:]:
            sum += eaechitem
            print(sum)
```

Comment: Try to think what your specific problem is and minimize the post so it contains only relevant code and information

Comment: `sum(k)` ?? does nothing.

Comment: hi Ni, I cut out the code that was not relevant to the question and added some comments. Perhaps it is more clear as to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example data you have given, to get the total of all lines that start with `file size` you can do the following:

```
xd = """Version 3.1.5.0
GetFileName C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads\\higgi022_20150612_007_bsadig_100fm_aft_newIonTrap3.raw
GetCreatorID    thermo
GetVersionNumber    64
file size   1010058
file size   200038
file size   48576986
file size   387905
misc    tester
more    python"""

total = 0

for line in xd.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('file size'):
        total += int(line.split()[2])

print(total)
```

This would display:

```
50174987
```

This first splits `xd` into lines, and for each line determines if it starts with the words `file size`. If it does it then uses `split()` to break the line into 3 parts. The third part contains the size as a string, so it needs to be converted to an integer using `int()`.

---

To extend this to work on a file, you would first need to read the file and total the necessary lines, and then open it in append mode to write the total:

```
with open('data.txt') as f_input:
    total = 0

    for line in f_input:
        if line.startswith('file size'):
            total += int(line.split()[2])

with open('data.txt', 'a') as f_output:
    f_output.write("\nTotal file size: {}\n".format(total))
```

---

Based on your current script, you could incorporate it as follows:

```
import os
import csv
from subprocess import run, PIPE

pathfile = 'C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads'
msfilepath = 'C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads\\msfilereader.py'

file_size_total = 0

with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as csvout:
    writer = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',')

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathfile):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".raw"):
                fp = os.path.join(root, f) #join the directory root and the file name
                p = run(['python', msfilepath, fp], stdout=PIPE) #run the MSfilereader.py path and each iterated raw file found
                p = p.stdout.decode('utf-8')

                for aline in p.split('\r\n'):
                   header = aline.split(' ', 1)
                   writer.writerows([header])

                   if 'END SECTION' in aline and aline.endswith('###'):
                        file_size = os.stat(fp).st_size
                        file_size_total += file_size
                        lst_filsz = ['file size', str(file_size)]
                        writer.writerow(lst_filsz)

    writer.writerow(["Total file size:", file_size_total])
```

This would give you a total of ALL `file size` entries. It would also be possible to add sub-totals for each section if that was required.

Note, when using `with open(....`, it is not necessary to also add a `close()` for the file, as soon as you leave the scope of the `with` statement, the file is automatically closed.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer, I appreciate your help. I'm sure your code would work but I can't manage to implement it into my existing code. I produce data for each file found from a separate .py file using a for loop + writerows, and at the end of this loop I manually add in the file size using an if statement that looks for the last row of each iteration. I guess it's not very good technique, but I got it to do what I wanted. However, I don't know how to iterate over the 'file size' row because (I think) it does not exist a priori. It has nothing to iterate over to sum the file sizes

Comment: If you are using `csv` then just add something like: `csv_output.writerow(['total size', total])` before closing the file (outside your loop)

Comment: Perhaps you could copy your script onto a site such as [0bin.net](https://0bin.net/) and post a link to it here.

Comment: Hi Martin, here is the link hosted by 0bin.net: https://0bin.net/paste/hnnJ2ZM7XpKYAX+v#

Comment: Don't think you've posted the right link, there is just a JSON object there.

Comment: I'm new to 0bin.net. I just simply copy and paste or upload the file with my code and send you the link? I tried it again, https://0bin.net/paste/paZGuAs3sTmTsExy#

Comment: I don't think you are giving the full URL. After clicking on the submit button, just copy the whole URL from the top of your browser to here, don't bother with trying to make a short URL (the feature might be broken). If you click on the link, it should show your original script (i.e. not something starting `{"iv":"..."`)

Comment: I was using the short url link. My apologies. Here is the full link, hopefully it works: https://0bin.net/paste/hKjrQF-SOsmYcqRu#osNVET4KuhWooyYkhqY08L5kV3vjEoQ0Kep8qKYqjlM Thanks!

Comment: Great, that worked better. Their short url system appears to be broken at the moment. I have updated the answer to give you a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks so much Martin! Appreciate your help :)